# how to change the to and from date from expression?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am getting json data from server ,In which I am getting the date expression like that "t+1", "t+2" ,"t-1"..**t** stand for current or system date .I need to change that these expression to date .if `t` is today date 2016-03-14. then `t-1` 2016-03-13.Can we change this expression in javascript

here is the object I am getting 
**Input**

```
   [
      {
        "column": {
          "name": "a",
          "userId": "dipu"

        },
        "deal": {
          "dealNumbers": [],
          "fromDateExpression": {
            "expression": "t-1",
            "date": "2016-03-08"
          },
          "toDateExpression": {
            "expression": "t",
            "date": "2016-03-08"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "column": {
          "name": "bb_test",
          "userId": "dipu"
        },
        "deal": {
          "dealNumbers": [
            "HH_2282825"
          ],
          "fromDateExpression": {
            "expression": "t+1",
            "date": "2016-03-09"
          },
          "toDateExpression": {
            "expression": "t+7",
            "date": "2016-03-17"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "column": {
          "name": "my view",
          "userId": "dipu",
          "associatedWithAView": false
        },
        "deal": {
          "dealNumbers": [
            "HH_2282759"
          ],
          "fromDateExpression": {
            "expression": "t+2",
            "date": "2016-02-19"
          },
          "toDateExpression": {
            "expression": "t+3",
            "date": "2016-02-19"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

I need to convert json array .I try like this

https://jsfiddle.net/e4nt1doz/1/

```
function changeDatefromExpress(expr){
if(expr=="t"){
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
return yyyy-mm-dd
}else(expr=="t+1"){

}
}
```

**Expected output is this**

```
[
  {
    "column": {
      "name": "a",
      "userId": "dipu"

    },
    "deal": {
      "dealNumbers": [],
      "fromDateExpression": {
        "expression": "t-1",
        "date": "2016-03-13"
      },
      "toDateExpression": {
        "expression": "t",
        "date": "2016-03-14"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "column": {
      "name": "bb_test",
      "userId": "dipu"
    },
    "deal": {
      "dealNumbers": [
        "HH_2282825"
      ],
      "fromDateExpression": {
        "expression": "t+1",
        "date": "2016-03-15"
      },
      "toDateExpression": {
        "expression": "t+7",
        "date": "2016-03-21"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "column": {
      "name": "my view",
      "userId": "dipu",
      "associatedWithAView": false
    },
    "deal": {
      "dealNumbers": [
        "HH_2282759"
      ],
      "fromDateExpression": {
        "expression": "t+2",
        "date": "2016-03-16"
      },
      "toDateExpression": {
        "expression": "t+3",
        "date": "2016-02-17"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

could I used regex..because there is lot of case like `t+5`,`t+6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about https://jsfiddle.net/xxhg2bvc/

(I want to make a point - code below is fully working)

```
Date.prototype.गांवारू=function(d){return new Date(this.valueOf()+864E5*d);};

function ლ_ಠ益ಠ_ლ(ಠ_ಠ){
    var π = ಠ_ಠ.getDate();
    var ಠ = ("0" + (ಠ_ಠ.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var शैतानआरहाहै = ಠ_ಠ.getFullYear();
    return शैतानआरहाहै+'-'+ಠ+'-'+π;
}

var जावास्क्रिप्ट = data.map(function(el){

    var Hͫ̆̒̐ͣ̊̄ͯ͗͏̵̗̻̰̠̬͝ͅE̴̷̬͎̱̘͇͍̾ͦ͊͒͊̓̓̐_̫̠̱̩̭̤͈̑̎̋ͮͩ̒͑̾͋͘Ç̳͕̯̭̱̲̣̠̜͋̍O̴̦̗̯̹̼ͭ̐ͨ̊̈͘͠M̶̝̠̭̭̤̻͓͑̓̊ͣͤ̎͟͠E̢̞̮̹͍̞̳̣ͣͪ͐̈T̡̯̳̭̜̠͕͌̈́̽̿ͤ̿̅̑Ḧ̱̱̺̰̳̹̘̰́̏ͪ̂̽͂̀͠  = new Date();
      el.deal.fromDateExpression.date = ლ_ಠ益ಠ_ლ(Hͫ̆̒̐ͣ̊̄ͯ͗͏̵̗̻̰̠̬͝ͅE̴̷̬͎̱̘͇͍̾ͦ͊͒͊̓̓̐_̫̠̱̩̭̤͈̑̎̋ͮͩ̒͑̾͋͘Ç̳͕̯̭̱̲̣̠̜͋̍O̴̦̗̯̹̼ͭ̐ͨ̊̈͘͠M̶̝̠̭̭̤̻͓͑̓̊ͣͤ̎͟͠E̢̞̮̹͍̞̳̣ͣͪ͐̈T̡̯̳̭̜̠͕͌̈́̽̿ͤ̿̅̑Ḧ̱̱̺̰̳̹̘̰́̏ͪ̂̽͂̀͠ .गांवारू(el.deal.fromDateExpression.expression.match(/t(.*)/)[1]));
      el.deal.toDateExpression.date = ლ_ಠ益ಠ_ლ(Hͫ̆̒̐ͣ̊̄ͯ͗͏̵̗̻̰̠̬͝ͅE̴̷̬͎̱̘͇͍̾ͦ͊͒͊̓̓̐_̫̠̱̩̭̤͈̑̎̋ͮͩ̒͑̾͋͘Ç̳͕̯̭̱̲̣̠̜͋̍O̴̦̗̯̹̼ͭ̐ͨ̊̈͘͠M̶̝̠̭̭̤̻͓͑̓̊ͣͤ̎͟͠E̢̞̮̹͍̞̳̣ͣͪ͐̈T̡̯̳̭̜̠͕͌̈́̽̿ͤ̿̅̑Ḧ̱̱̺̰̳̹̘̰́̏ͪ̂̽͂̀͠ .गांवारू(el.deal.toDateExpression.expression.match(/t(.*)/)[1]));

      return el;
})
console.log(जावास्क्रिप्ट);
```

Comment: it is not same as expected.please remove your answer

Comment: Thanks for help ..can we change the format of date yyyy-mm-dd..example like that 2016-03-15

Comment: you can include your code for this since you already written it

Comment: the one from `changeDatefromExpress`

Comment: sorry ..I didn't get after creating the date ..I am not able to format the date

Comment: just join those `return yyyy + mm + dd`

Comment: please change on fiddle ?